# OpenEJB and JEE7

Tags: jakarta-ee, openejb, java-ee-7

Does anybody knows if or when OpenEJB is going to support JEE7? I am trying to use JMS 2.0  with OpenEJB 4.6.0 but got an InitializationException at the startup of the container.

I know that I could use Arquillian but I was wondering if it also works with OpenEJB.

Answer (score 1):

Tomcat 8 is not yet ready, so I guess JEE7 for TomEE will take some time.
Btw., I don't understand what you mean with that Arquillian note - Arquillian is a testing framework, not a Java EE container. If you want a working JEE7 container, try WildFly or GlassFish.

Comment: Like you said I can use Wildfly and GlassFish as a JEE7 container and these are easily usable with Arquillian. Thats what I meant. In this case I will wait for Tomcat 8. By the way there is an alpha version of Tomcat 8 available since end of December.

Comment: @tobiasdenzler, Tomcat8 is just a servlet container, all other dependencies should fully implement it for JEE7.